# A better way of organizing the query React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What if I want **limit** and **offset** to be optional? Let's say I have two actions which call this method

1. ProductRelatedDetail(catId, subCatId)
2. ProductRelatedDetail(catId,
   subCatId, limit, offset)

I don't want to duplicate the function twice. What is the better and more dynamic way of managing this kind of situations?

```
export function ProductRelatedDetail(catId, subCatId, limit, offset) {

  return function (dispatch) {

        return fetch(`${constants.API}?tag=product_list&category_id=${catId}&sub_category_id=${subCatId}&limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: myHeaders,
        })
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => dispatch({
                    type: actionType.GET_RELATED_DETAIL,
                    payload: data
              })).catch(error => {
                    console.log('Got cat Feed', error);
              });
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an if statement as follows:

```
export function ProductRelatedDetail(catId, subCatId, limit, offset) {

return function (dispatch) {
    if(!limit && !offset){
    return fetch(`${constants.API}?tag=product_list&category_id=${catId}&sub_category_id=${subCatId}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
    })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => dispatch({
                type: actionType.GET_RELATED_DETAIL,
                payload: data
          })).catch(error => {
                console.log('Got cat Feed', error);
          });
    }else{
        return fetch(`${constants.API}?tag=product_list&category_id=${catId}&sub_category_id=${subCatId}&limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
    })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => dispatch({
                type: actionType.GET_RELATED_DETAIL,
                payload: data
          })).catch(error => {
                console.log('Got cat Feed', error);
          });
    }
 }
};
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible that you could do something like this:

```
return fetch(
"${constants.API}?tag=product_list&category_id=${catId}&sub_category_id=${subCatId}" 
+ ((limit!=null) ? "&limit=${limit}" : "") 
+ ((offset!=null) ? "&offset=${offset}" : ""), ...
```